# Use package.json variables in my config.router.js

Tags: angularjs

I want to use package.json's variable in my config.router.js.
I am currently using 
var readJson = require('./package.json');
but it is giving me error.

Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.6/$injector/modulerr?p0=app&p1=ReferenceErr…host%2FInMotionNow%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A19%3A83)

Comment: What is the error it gives you? What have your tried already to fix it? Are you sure the path is correct? I presume your using `browserify` to build the client code? You really need to give more information for people to be able to help you.

Comment: It gives me this error:Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.6/$injector/modulerr?p0=app&p1=ReferenceErr…host%2FInMotionNow%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A19%3A83)

Comment: How are you trying to use your `package.json` in Angular? Are you using `browserify`, `requirejs` etc to build your client source server side? If you look through your built source is the package.json in there?